# Get vertex properties information in simple format

Tags: json, gremlin, graphson

Let's say I have two nodes 'A' and 'B' in graph with each node having 'name' (string) and 'roll-no' (int) properties. How can I write the query to get the node properties information in below format. Please note that I don't need data type information and nested json structure in the output.

```
[{name=[apple], roll-no=[10,20]}, {name=[mango], roll-no=[30]}]
```

I think I'm asking for how to convert GraphSON to normal JSON.

Comment: I'm using tinkerpop3. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `project()` the element into a `Map`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project('name','age').by('name').by('age')
==>[name:marko,age:29]
```

As you can see, taking this approach allows you to control how the map is produced in a more fine grained fashion as you control the properties in the `by()` step modulators. If the returned vertices do not have homogeneous property keys you will need to account for that in some way - here's one possibility:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('name','age').
......1>   by('name').
......2>   by(coalesce(values('age'),constant('none')))
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:lop,age:none]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:ripple,age:none]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

Without using project you might also do something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().local(properties().group().by(key()).by(value()))
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:lop,lang:java]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:ripple,lang:java]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

Not quite as clear as `project()` and will get all properties which is generally discouraged, but obviously that approach will work. I guess you could itemize the properties to get though as follows:

```
gremlin> g.V().local(properties('name','age').group().by(key()).by(value()))
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:lop]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:ripple]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

Comment: It works for a single node but not for multiple nodes. g.V().project('name','age').by('name').by('age')

Comment: it will work for multiple vertices, but you have to account for vertices which might not have a particular property. Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: `project()` is good if you need to take missing properties into account, otherwise I would just use `valueMap("name","age")`. `properties(...).group().by(...)` looks a bit overcomplicated to me.

Comment: `valueMap()` doesn't work in this case. the question was about getting rid of the underlying multi-property wrapping in the map.